# there are three a user clicks on certain JButtons named red, blue, pink and one Jlabel

Tags: java

there are three a user clicks on certain JButtons named red, blue, pink and one Jlabel. Add ActionListener to buttons such that if button, foreground color of label will change accordingly

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Worst question title I ever saw, but I guess the question is how to change the foreground color of a label based on three buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // red is your jbutton
    if(e.getName().equals("red")){
        //change lbl color to red
    }
    else if(e.getName().equals("blue")){
        //change lbl color to blue
    }
 }
```